# How to use variable for url parameter in jquery ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"hostname/projfolder/webservice.php?callback=statusReturn&content="+str_table,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain:true,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        success:function statusReturn(data)
            {
            alert("in success");
            var parsedata=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                var stats=parsedata["Status"];

            if("1"==stats)
            {   
                alert("success");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("failed");
            }
            }
        });
```

How can I display the contents of the "url" parameter in an alertbox to check what the parameter is containing?

It does not even enter in the "success" parameter. Please suggest me how can I do that.

Comment: Ahh, alert debugging, those days... You can use `console.log` or even breakpoints these days for debugging. Also check your network tab to see what happens to the network request

Comment: Before using alert to see contents of str_table, i tried doing console.log but it does not print anything, and it shows contents when I display alerts. Don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put you url parameter in a variable like so:

```
var targetUrl = "hostname/projfolder/webservice.php?callback=statusReturn&content="+str_table";
//log your output
console.log(targetUrl, str_table);
```

Then use it in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: targetUrl,
    ...
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5Ppf/) for full example

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.url` if need to access within event of ajax call. All parameters of ajax call can be accessed via `this` object. So final statement will be

```
alter(this.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see your request parameter in firbug plugin of chrom or firefox